# how to add percentage column in ssrs

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix in report builder to generate for each employee the actual balance per Fiscal_year where fiscal_year is columns group.

I need to add a field to calculate YOY% between years selected in the parameters
for example if i selected in parameters Fiscal_year 2018, 2017, I should have in addition to 2018 actual balance, and 2017 actual balance, YOY% = (2018 AB -2017 AB)/2017 AB

The formula should take into consideration dividing by zero.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The comparison in a single report will be between 2 years or could be for more year couples like 2018-2017, 2017-2016, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the below formula, it also take into consideration dividing by zero:

```
=IIF(SUM(iif(Fields!FISCAL_YEAR.Value = 2017,cdbl(Fields!actual_BAL.Value),0.00))=0,0,(SUM(iif(Fields!FISCAL_YEAR.Value = 2018,cdbl(Fields!actual_BAL.Value),0.00))-SUM(iif(Fields!FISCAL_YEAR.Value = 2017,cdbl(Fields!actual_BAL.Value),0.00)))/IIF(SUM(iif(Fields!FISCAL_YEAR.Value = 2017,cdbl(Fields!actual_BAL.Value),0.00))=0,1,SUM(iif(Fields!FISCAL_YEAR.Value = 2017,cdbl(Fields!actual_BAL.Value),0.00))))*100
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create this column in the SQL query, I had the same problem earlier this week.

Create a query in SQL with the following:

```
With Year2017AB as (
select column names, cast(actual_bal as float) as Balance7 
from data
where fiscal_year = '2017')
, Year2018AB as (
select column names, cast(actual_bal as float) as Balance8
from data
where fiscal_year = '2018')
select name column, Balance7, Balance8, (Balance8-Balance7)/Balance7 as YOY% 
from data d
left join Year Year2017AB s
on d.name = s.name
left join Year2018AB e
on d.name = e.name
```

Be sure to cast the values into float so the actual answer will be read. Format it into a percent in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should be something like

```
=CStr(IIF(Parameter!<paramname>.Value ="2018, 2017", IIF(SUM(Fields!2017AB.Value > 0 ,SUM(Fields!2017AB.Value -Fields!2017AB.Value)/SUM(Fields!2017AB.Value),0)) & "%"
```

Do not use sum if there is no grouping the row where you are displaying the AB values.